# What is it doing? (HASH, RAWTOHEX)

Tags: sql, hash, netezza

I've been given this SQL query (using Netezza) & there's a function I've not used before - it returns a key but I don't know where it's getting it from?:

```
select LOWER(SYSTEM..RAWTOHEX(SYSTEM..HASH(PROFILEID||'TK'||'CUST_V1',1))), ...
```

Can someone explain what it's doing?

Comment: You're using product specific functions. Tag the dbms used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is using a [SHA-1 hash](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_hash.html) of the values in `PROFILEID` concatenated with 'TKCUST_V1'. (Why that's separated into two concats is beyond me.)

This is likely to return a not very human readable result, as the docs show:

> ```
> select hash('Netezza',0);
>        HASH
> ------------------
> Ã
> Â®dÃ¯O=ÂÂ±NEÂ
> ÂÂÃ
> (1 row)
> ```

So the creator called `RAWTOHEX` to translate it from a byte string to a hex string. `RAWTOHEX` will return some hexadecimal value like this.

```
8D812C9E8DB362FCB20E
```

Finally, it's translated to a lowercase form.